# Change image src with image list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I want to make image lists array or html list and whenever I hover on my image it must change one by one with fade or slide effect and whevever I hoverout my image must change with default images

question 1: whant kind of list that I have to create? html list or array ?

question 2:  I create span to get image url with data-src for example is that markup and right ?

[click to see demo link on codepen](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/pNVzdb)

HTML

```
<div class="img-area">
 <img src="http://cdn.anitur.com.tr/resimler/logo/2016-11/otel_granada-luxury-belek_9cca25crBlK2lNq0AS5H.jpg" alt="">
    <span data-src="http://cdn.anitur.com.tr/resimler/logo/2014-12/otel_lykia-world-links-golf_UIaJYkbajuilxPCGYzxM.jpg">
    <span data-src="http://cdn.anitur.com.tr/resimler/logo/2014-12/otel_lykia-world-links-golf_UIaJYkbajuilxPCGYzxM.jpg">
 </div>

   <div class="img-area">
 <img src="http://cdn.anitur.com.tr/resimler/logo/2014-12/otel_lykia-world-links-golf_qtNSeosTlMq2dDG35zvY.jpg" alt="">
     <span data-src="http://cdn.anitur.com.tr/resimler/logo/2014-12/otel_lykia-world-links-golf_OnYNchpgK6PJmucaHMHN.jpg">
```

and my js but I didn't know what I write

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".img-area img").hover(function(){
   $(this).parents(".img-area").find("img");
 })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change images in interval using

```
function changeImage(img){
    // document.getElementById('bigImage').src=img;
    setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById('bigImage').src=img;},1250);
}
```

Comment: is that impossible just getting source of img not with position I want to learn to how to get src and how to change img with each or settimeout this is not important but I want to learn it just curiosity

Comment: I mean I have a list on demo link and when I hover on image my default image must change with image list one by one with fade or slide effect or without

Comment: span data-src has img source

Comment: use `$('bigImage').prop("src",$(this).parents(".img-area > span").eq(i).prop("data-src"))` where i is ur iterator

Comment: actually I just have a html structure and on this page http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/pNVzdb